# Serial port : not able to write big chunk of data

Tags: linux, serial-port

I am trying to send text data from one PC to other using Serial cable. One of the PC is running linux and I am sending data from it using write(2) system call. The log size is approx 65K bytes but the write(2) system call returns some 4K bytes (i.e. this much amount of data is getting transferred). I tried breaking the data in chunks of 4K but write(2) returns -1.

My question is that "Is there any buffer limit for writing data on serial port? or can I send data of any size?. Also do I need to continously read data from other PC as I write 4K chunk of data"

Do I need to do any special configuration in termios structure for sending (huge) data?

Comment: Would it be easy for you to post the code snippet that writes the data in 4K chunks?

Answer (score 1):

The transmit buffer is one page (took a look at Linux 2.6.18 sources) - which is 4K in most (if not all) cases.

The other end must read (don't know the size of the receive buffer), but more importantly you should not write faster than the serial port can transmit, if you are using 115200 bps 8-N-1 you can write the 4K chunk approximately 3 times a second. (115200 / 9 / 4096 = 3.125)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a buffer limit - but when you reach that limit, the `write()` should block.

When `write()` returns -1, what is `errno` set to?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the receiver is reading.

You should update the current position it your buffer from the write(), and continue the next write from there. (Applies to all writes(), regardless if the fd is a serial port, tcp socket or a file.)

If you get an error back for subsequent writes. Judging by the manpage, its safe to retry the writes for the following errnos: EAGAIN, EINTR, and probably ENOSPC.  Use perror() to see what you get. (..and post it, I am curious.)

EFBIG would seem to indicate that you are trying to write using a buffer (or rather count) that is too large, but that is probably much larger than 64k.

If the internal buffer is filled up, because you are writing to fast, try to (nano)sleep a little between the writes. There are several clever ways of doing this (like tcp does), but if the rate is known, just write at a fixed rate.

If you think the receiver is actually reading, but not much happens, have a look at the serial ports flow-control options and if the cable is wired for DTS/RTS.

Comment: "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment" by W. Richard Stevens (or actually anyone of his books)  is mandatory reading if you are going to do anything important.